# Verify that terms of use that are in a different tab are checked before form is submitted

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform

In the add a customer form  in the admin site I added a tab (consents) that has the terms of use and they are required, but if the person does not click into the tab then the form is submitted even though the terms have not been checked off. How can I be sure the the "terms of use" is checked off or the form cannot be submitted. Thank you for you help ahead of time

[image]

[image]